# How do I add JSON get method in my android app

Tags: json, android-studio, org.json

I am trying to develop a simple android app where a user can enter a username and password and then when they click login, it compares the information with that in the database. If the information is correct, then a new activity is opened showing success message. I would like to use JSON get method. I already have an API key for this but am an absolute beginner so any help on how to go about this will be highly appreciated

Comment: What are you asking?  How to use JSONObject to serialize/deserialize the data?  Are you looking for a JSON RPC client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to take `Username` and `Password` as input from user and then want to call an API for authentication.
Suppose your input json object looks something like this

```
{
"Username":"myName",
"Password":"qwerty"
}
```

then you can get the required information like

```
jsonObject.get("Username");
```

this will return you the user entered name and same goes for password as well
then you can call the authentication API using this information.

Comment: Yes that's what I hope to accomplish Ratish... Could you please send me that answer in an xml format since I am using Android Studio to create this app

Comment: I didn't understood your ask for xml format? You would implementing the app in java right?